# req.params not working inside $limit in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i tried to get the url params of lim (check the code listed below) with value 5 to limit the search result so i passed the req.params.lim inside $limit but its not working, but when i tried with normal variable with a assigned value of 5 its working good. so please help me out.

```
app.get('/search/:q/:lim',function(req,res){
db.jobs.aggregate({$match:{$text:{$search:req.params.q}}},{$sort:{score:{$meta:"textScore"}}},
 {$limit:req.params.lim},function(err,docs){res.send({data:docs});});
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that is nit a string? Try wrapping with parseInt

Comment: localhost:3000/jobs/5  this resembles /search/:q/:lim  its not a string its a number can u help me how to do it

Comment: thank you @NeilLunn now its working with parseint and can u explain me why it is working with parsetint and not a usual one ?

Comment: Request parameters are typically passed in as strings. Even with something like JSON formatted data in a post body, it usually requires a body parser plugin in order to massage this into a usable data structure. So since `$limit` requires a number and not a string, you need to make sure that is what you are giving it.

Comment: now i am clear thank you @NeilLunn for this wonderful answer