# Passing argument to mongoose nested query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I don't understand why I'm getting 504 Gateway timeouts.

```
app.get("/api/exercise/log", function(req,res) {
  let userId = req.query.userId;
  let from = req.query.from;
  let to = req.query.to;
  let limit = req.query.limit;
  console.log("limit1 " + limit);
  User.findById(userId).exec(function (err,data) {
    console.log("limit2 " + limit);
    if (err) return err;
    Exercise.find({userId: userId}).limit(limit).exec(function (err2,data2) {
      console.log("limit3 " + limit);
      if (err2) return err2;
      let logArr = [];
      logArr.push(data2);
      let total = logArr[0].length;
      let answer = Object.assign({}, data._doc, {log: logArr}, {total: total});  
      res.json(answer);
    })    
  })  
})
```

My url ends with log?userId=555&limit=2. All the console logs (limit1, limit2, limit3) prints out '2' as it's supposed to, however I don't get any results, only timeouts. If I change that line to enter the limit manually, like

```
Exercise.find({userId: userId}).limit(2).exec(function (err2,data2) {
```

everything works and I get the correct number of results. What is this all about?

Comment: `.limit(parseInt(limit))`. All params are "strings" and the function is expecting a numeric value. So you need `parseInt()` or similar to convert it.

Comment: Lol. Got it, thanks.

Comment: Funny thing is the only other related question I could find here is [something I also commented on years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23751643/2313887) and that also never got an answer :(. Web server requests are "strings", so always remember to convert them. Bit surprised that the mongoose wrapper for `limit()` does not do that automatically though. Considering the whole "schema" approach to do typecasting just about everywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change limit to number using parseInt and check whether the value can be converted to number or not.

```
app.get("/api/exercise/log", function(req,res) {
  let userId = req.query.userId;
  let from = req.query.from;
  let to = req.query.to;
  let limit = 10;
  if(!isNaN(req.query.limit)){
      limit = parseInt(req.query.limit);   // use limit from query params if it is a valid number
  }
  console.log("limit1 " + limit);
  User.findById(userId).exec(function (err,data) {
    console.log("limit2 " + limit);
    if (err) return err;
    Exercise.find({userId: userId}).limit(limit).exec(function (err2,data2) {
      console.log("limit3 " + limit);
      if (err2) return err2;
      let logArr = [];
      logArr.push(data2);
      let total = logArr[0].length;
      let answer = Object.assign({}, data._doc, {log: logArr}, {total: total});  
      res.json(answer);
    })    
  })  
})
```